# Creating Types in Elasticsearch with NEST

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, nest

So I a built a very basic Elastic example using just one Type (Products) I was able to use automap to build this and all worked well, now I want to expand on this and add more types I am running into issues but without any real exceptions being thrown to give me a clue as to what is going wrong.

```
class Product
    {

        public int ProductId { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string ProductCode { get; set; }
        public string Barcode { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> ProductCategoryId { get; set; }
        public int Length { get; set; }
        public int Height { get; set; }
        public int ProductTypeId { get; set; }
        public string Url { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> ProductBrandId { get; set; }
        public int Width { get; set; }
        public string Html { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public string MetaTitle { get; set; }
        public string MetaKeywords { get; set; }
        public string MetaDescription { get; set; }
        public decimal CostPrice { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> ProductBuyingPriceId { get; set; }
        public int DispatchTimeInDays { get; set; }
        public int LeadTimeInDays { get; set; }
        public string ManufacturerPartNumber { get; set; }
        public string Notes { get; set; }
        public int StockAvailable { get; set; }
        public decimal WeightKg { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> SellingPriceGroupId { get; set; }
        public Nullable<decimal> ReviewRating { get; set; }
        public int ReviewRatingCount { get; set; }
        public bool NonReturnable { get; set; }
        public bool LimitedStock { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> TaxRateId { get; set; }

        public virtual ProductCategory ProductCategory { get; set; }

    }

    class ProductCategory
    {
        public int ProductCategoryId { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> ParentProductCategoryId { get; set; }
        public string FullPath { get; set; }
        public string Code { get; set; }
    }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            var des = new CreateIndexDescriptor("myindex")
                .Mappings(ms => ms
                .Map<Product>(m => m.AutoMap())
                .Map<ProductCategory>(m => m.AutoMap())
                );

            var res = elasticClient.CreateIndex(des);
            Output.AppendText(res.ToString());
            Output.AppendText(Environment.NewLine);
            Output.AppendText("Index Created");
            Output.AppendText(Environment.NewLine);


        }
```

As mentioned if I just Include  it works fine if I add Product Category nothing happens. TIA

Comment: Note that `Nullable<int>` should be written `int?` so as to not make my eyes bleed.

Comment: Are you repopulating a new aliased index and swopping it out with the existing one?

Comment: @MatthewEvans Im deleting the index and recreating it

Comment: @rs82uk  What happens if you run GET /_aliases/ against ES?

Comment: Ok after adding some error handling to my code I have got an error which helps Rejecting mapping update to [sterlingbuild] as the final mapping would have more than 1 type: [product, productcategory] After doing some reading it turns out that ES6 cannot have more than one type, so everything should just be within product is this correct?

Comment: @rs82uk Elasticsearch 6.0 can only have a single type per index. It's possible to construct Parent/Child relationships: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/master/parent-child-relationships.html if that is the mapping you need, otherwise you can map as `ProductCategory` property on `Product` as a `nested` type: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.1/nested.html

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the responses As Russ said I was trying to have multiple types which wouldn't work